# How to display logs in release mode?

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8, logging

I am currently working on a Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight) library in wich one I am trying to display some logs into the console throw the `Debug.WriteLine` method.

While the library is under *Debug* mode I can see the output of the `Debug.WriteLine` method but when the library is under *Release* mode nothing is displayed.

According to the .NET documentation, I can use the `Trace` class in order to display some logs even in *Release* mode but this class does not exist into the Windows Phone library.

I also tried to use the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]` annotation but it does not work.

So the question is : how can I display logs into the console event if a library (or an app project) is running into *Release* mode ?

Edit : It seems to work if I use the `Debugger` class. Is it a good practice ?

Comment: The Release build is suitable for the version of your app that runs on the user's phone.  Which most certainly doesn't have a console.  Nor is the user going to be interested in your debug trace, he simply expects it to work without hassle.   Use the Debug build to test your app.

Comment: @HansPassant : Thx for your answer. These logs are not for the user but for the developpers which are going to integrate my library to their apps. My library is going to be built into release mode but with some configurations, the developpers will be able to enable or disable the logs.